# MongoDB sort data by most number of records

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to sort with the most occurrences of any value in a collection.

Eg.

```
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Apple'
}, 
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Banana'
}, 
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Apple'
}, 
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Orange'
}, 
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Apple'
}, 
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Banana'
}, 
{
  "id": "ID",
  "fruit": 'Apple'
}
```

I need fruit with the name Apple should on top because Apple occurs more time than other fruit in above collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`"$sortByCount"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortByCount/) aggregation stage to accomplish this.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sortByCount": "$fruit"
  }
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "Apple",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "Banana",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "Orange",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DID_gAhMz82).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the aggregation framework to do that.

You can use [this MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n4AxIINMwWh) to test it, you need to run the following aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$fruit",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      documents: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      count: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$documents"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$documents"
  }
])
```